# How to set different properties from objects which are returned by the Factory pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern, abstract-factory

I was wondering on how to set properties on which objects which are returned by the concrete factory. The factory can return objectA with properties A and B, but it can also return objectB with properties X, Y, Z.

Since the client only know the interface objectA and objectB inherits, it doesn't know which object he is dealing with. So, my question is, what is the OO way of setting these properties? Do I need to introduce a kind of setting class, which contains all the properties of classA and classB? But this isn't OO, because when there's a new class I have to update the setting class as well...

I hope you undserstand my question and can help me out :)

PS: If it matters, I am working with C#

Answer (score 1):

You can use a visitor which knows which properties to set and can assign it to the concrete class which you get (inside the factory). Now this visitor can set the desired properties in abstract way.

```
class Factory {

..
obj = new ConcreteObject();
obj.accept(new ConcreteObjectVisitor());
}

class ConcreteObject{

accept(Visitor visitor){
 visitor.visit(this);
}

}

class ConcreteObjectVisitor implements Visitor {

visit(ConcretTypeInterface param){

obj = (ConcretType)param;
param.setA()
param.setB()
param.setC()
}
}
```

Comment: I am not that familiar with the visitor pattern, but should I use the visitor pattern in combination with the abstract factory pattern?

Comment: Thanks, but how does the ConcreteObjectVisitor get its values? Suppose that the client knows the password and username, how does the ConcreteObjectVisitor gets these values?

Comment: ConcreteObjectVisitor get values via parameters: ConcreteObject o = factory.GetObject(); Visitor v = new Visitor(); v.SetParams(Params p);  o.accept(v);

Comment: So, when the client needs to set some properties, the client needs to know about the Visitor, then the client can send this visitor as a parameter to factory. Is this right?

Comment: You can make the Factory class responsible for setting up the initial parameters. Because Factory knows the concrete type, that should be easy to do: ConcreteObject o = factory.GetObject(Params initialParams);

Comment: But not every concrete type has the same properties. I mean concreteObjectA has different properties than concreteObjectB. How should you solve this?

Comment: You need to provide the appropriate props to set and then each visitor should know which params should be set to each concrete object (which it received from the factory). Could you post code which you have tried and highlight the confusion point ?

Answer (score 1):

If client needs to set values of properties that don't exist in common interface, it has to have some knowledge on concrete types of objects that the factory has created. There are several approaches to this:

1. Client decides what kind of object it needs and calls appropriate factory operation. So for this scenario, the factory would have a different operations for creating objectA and objectB. Values of properties to be set could be passed as parameters of those operations.
2. Client decides what kind of object it needs and passes this decision to factory as a value of a parameter of factory method. The values themselves are passed as a single array, collection or dictionary object in another parameter.
3. Factory decides what class to instantiate, passes new instance to client and then client discovers the concrete class of given object (in C# via GetType() method). If concrete class is accessible to client, it can perform a cast, if not, it can set values of properties using reflection.

If examples are needed, just write a comment :-)